# Django and Angularjs - Incorrect json property name is send with post to api

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I need some guidance here, still new to django and Angularjs.

I have the django rest framework setup to display my departments with the below json returned.

primary_locations is a foreignkey to my locations model.

```
[
    {
        "id": 52,
        "department_name": "Technical",
        "department_description": "Technical",
        "primary_locations": {
            "id": 1,
            "location_name": "ZA",
            "address": "ZA",
            "city": "ZA",
            "province": "ZA",
            "postal_code": "ZA",
            "country": "AG"
        }
    }
]
```

In Angular I have a dropdown list that displays the available locations to select from.

When I post the selected option I receive an error saying the following.

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"IntegrityError at
>   /department\n(1048, \"Column 'primary_locations_id' cannot be null

But when I scroll further down the page it shows the below was posted to the api

```
{"department_name":"as","department_description":"as","locations":"4"},
```

Why is Angularjs sending the primary_locations_id name as locations and not primary_locations_id?

**Here is my controller**

```
system.controller('DepartmentCtrl', ['$scope', 'DepartmentsFactory', 'DepartmentFactory', 'LocationFactory', '$location',
    function ($scope, DepartmentsFactory, DepartmentFactory, LocationFactory, $location) {

        // Function to reload content on success
        $scope.reloadDepartments = function () {
            DepartmentsFactory.query( function( data ) {
              $scope.departments = data;
            });
        };

        // callback for ng-click 'editDepartment':
        $scope.editDepartment = function (id) {
            $location.path('/department/' + id);
        };

        // callback for ng-click 'deleteDepartment':

        $scope.deleteDepartment = function (id) {
            DepartmentFactory.delete({ id: id }, function() {
                $scope.reloadDepartments();
            });
        };

        // callback for ng-click 'createDepartment':
        $scope.createNewDepartment = function () {
            DepartmentsFactory.create($scope.department, function() {
                $scope.reloadDepartments();
            });
        };

        $scope.departments = DepartmentsFactory.query();
        $scope.locations = LocationFactory.query();
    }]);
```

**Here is my Serializer**

```
class DepartmentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer to represent the Departments model """
    class Meta:
        model = Departments
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**Here is my service**

```
system.factory('DepartmentsFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/department', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});

system.factory('LocationFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/location/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET' }
    })
});
```

**Here is my angular view (ng-controller is specified further up in my code, I have not listed that part of the code in the below snippet)**

```
<select ng-model="department.locations" name=“department.primary_locations_id” class="form-control input-sm">
  <option ng-repeat="location in locations" value="{{location.id}}">{{location.location_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: post your typscript code.

Comment: Hi Usman, thanks for responding, Is the code in my controller section not the correct code you are after?

Comment: Managed to resolve this.